# How to get 256 color support for FreeBSD headless console/terminal?

Tags: terminal, colors, freebsd, ncurses, terminfo

How can I get 256 color support on FreeBSD 13 headless machine using console/terminal?

I have an overkill GPU "AMD Radeon PRO WX 2100" installed to the machine.

Basically want to avoid a desktop environment since I only need to use the machine purely based only for "text" wise.

The machine will be used to display real time stock pricing and I would like to use color highlighting to make the text based real time charting terminal/console application more user friendly and readable.

I can not find any comprehensible or easy guide to do so and have no idea where to begin.

I am using ncurses to make the app.

When I type `tput color` to the console, I get a return of a value `80`.

Comment: headless means no access through  a terminal, but only access through a serial or a network link from another computer. With `FreeBSD`, the console is either `vt` or `sc`, behavior and features are not the same.

Comment: Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic here. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

OP misuses the term "headless" for non-desktop, but the intent is clear from the reference to ncurses.  This refers to text-mode in a FreeBSD console.

Short: you can't do that.

Longer: without X (desktop), unless you're going to develop a terminal emulator in which to run ncurses using 256-colors on FreeBSD, you're out of luck.  See for instance [`concol`](https://github.com/rofl0r/concol) (perhaps a starting point, but nothing that you could actually use with ncurses).

Many users are misled by a FreeBSD developer's choice to set the `TERM` variable of the newer console terminal emulator to "xterm", supposing that it can display 256 colors.  This is mentioned near the end of the XTerm FAQ [*"Can I set a color by its number"*](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#color_by_number), which goes into some detail explaining how the 256-color feature came about.  There's a [screenshot](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/images/teken-256colors.png) for teken (the proper name for the FreeBSD console emulator) which shows its inability to render 256-colors.  Aside from changing the palette to shift it toward the red colors, it's unchanged since 2014.

[image: xterm vs FreeBSD 256-colors]

FreeBSD documentation refers to *teken* as "vt".  Like the older "sc" (syscons), that only works for VGA colors (8 ANSI colors combined with bright/bold attribute to simulate 16 colors).

The FreeBSD console terminal emulator is documented in the ncurses terminal database section on the [FreeBSD console](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#toc-_Free_B_S_D_console_entries) emulators.  In particular, there is a lengthy comment on this one before the [`teken-2018`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-teken-2018) entry.

---

Regarding this:

> When I type tput color to the console, I get a return of a value 80.

That is a misfeature of the FreeBSD configuration.  Its *system* utility [**`tput`**](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=tput&apropos=0&sektion=1&manpath=FreeBSD%2013.1-RELEASE%20and%20Ports&arch=default&format=html) imitates the older termcap-based utility which (see the [manual page](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/tput.1.html#h2-HISTORY)) Keith Bostic wrote in 1989 imitating the AT&T [**`tput`**](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=tput&apropos=0&sektion=1&manpath=SunOS%205.5.1&arch=default&format=html) utility.  That's actually a few years too late to be regarded as "original termcap", but most users don't know the difference.  Anyway, as a **termcap** utility (on the surface), only the first two characters of that **`color`** are used, giving **`co`** (termcap equivalent for **`columns`**).  The termcap name for **`colors`** is **`Co`** (see [manual page](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/terminfo.5.html#h3-Predefined-Capabilities)):

```
      max_colors                  colors    Co     maximum number of
                                                   colors on screen
```

A termcap application would not understand the terminal descriptions used for colors in ncurses.  This happens to sort-of work (for 16 colors) in the FreeBSD console because underneath the facade it is the terminfo-based ncurses library.

---

Some users are confused by the distinction between text and graphical VGA modes.  A non-desktop environment uses text mode, which provides for 3 bits  (8 text colors) combined with one bit which is often treated as ***bold***, making 16 colors.

In a *graphical* mode, one can use a [splash screen](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?splash(4)), with 256 colors.  That is unrelated to *text* modes.

The `vidcontrol` program shows the available colors for the current video mode.  It can list available *modes* as shown here.  Only a few are usable for **text** (and all of those are as noted VGA):

[image: vidcontrol showing video mode summaries]

It can also show the colors with the caveat that different releases of FreeBSD have widely differing video capabilities.  Here are screenshots from FreeBSD 11

[image: FreeBSD 11 vidcontrol show]

FreeBSD 12

[image: FreeBSD 12 vidcontrol show]

and FreeBSD 13 (where vidcontrol presents no choices):

[image: FreeBSD 13 vidcontrol show]

Perhaps the lack of mode information from the FreeBSD 13 indicates that someone intends making it work with one of the graphic modes, as hinted in the manual page.  But the color palette is not improved, yet.  The manual page says for example

> Note: The vt VGA hardware driver does not support palette configuration.

Further reading:

- [FreeBSD Splash Screens](https://www.baldwin.cx/splash/)
- [syscons, sc -- the console driver](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sc&apropos=0&sektion=4&manpath=FreeBSD%2013.1-RELEASE%20and%20Ports&arch=default&format=html)
- [vt -- virtual terminal console driver](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=vt&apropos=0&sektion=4&manpath=FreeBSD%2013.1-RELEASE%20and%20Ports&arch=default&format=html)
- [vidcontrol](https://cgit.freebsd.org/src/tree/usr.sbin/vidcontrol/vidcontrol.c) (source code)
- [teken](https://cgit.freebsd.org/src/tree/sys/dev/syscons/scterm-teken.c) (source code)

Comment: `sc` is not defunct at all ! [FreeBSD syscons commit log on git](https://cgit.freebsd.org/src/log/sys/dev/syscons) ; I use it since 15 years now, and it render very well my 256 colors splash screen ! Hey guy, why are you talking about emulation ? Anyway, if you want to play with the console, you have to play with `vidcontrol` and see what it says about your screen features. No more to say here, as said above, question is more about OS than devel.